# Function returns false but i need why return true react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Hi people i new in react native whit expo and i have a problem...

I have this function in another file :

```
const login = async(email, password) => {
    axios.post('/login', {
        email : email,
        password: password
    }).then(response  => {
        let info = response.data.data.token
        AsyncStorage.setItem('scute-user-token', info)
    }).catch(error => {
        Alert.alert(error)
    })
    const Scutetoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scute-user-token')
    if (Scutetoken !== null ){
        return true 
    } else {
        return false 
    }
}
```

and I call in :

```
 login = async() => {
    const login = await funciones.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    console.log(login)
    if(login == true){
      const me = funciones.yo()
       if(me == true){
         this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
       } else{
         await AsyncStorage.clear()
         Alert.alert('No se puede acceder en este momento')
       }
    } 
  }
```

¿The problem? the problem its why the function always return false even if save the token i try solved of different ways but i not found solution....

Thx 4 the answers

Comment: I think you might need `await` in front of your call to `axios.post`. Not sure if that is the only problem though. The problem looks like the call to `AsyncStorage.getItem` is reached before `axios.post` completes because `axios.post` is asynchronous.

Comment: Slightly borderline dupe of [how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), potentially some extra notes as to why the same principle applies would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const login = async(email, password) => {
    axios.post('/login', {
        email : email,
        password: password
    }).then(response  => {
        let info = response.data.data.token
        AsyncStorage.setItem('scute-user-token', info)
    }).catch(error => {
        Alert.alert(error)
    })
    const Scutetoken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('scute-user-token')
    if (Scutetoken !== null ){
        return true 
    } else {
        return false 
    }
}
```

Depending of how long your POST request to '/login' lasts, the moment your getting your token, the request might be not finished. So that's why your ScuteToken is going to be null.

Call  `await axios.post() ...` so it will wait for the call to be finished.

Answer (score 0):

`axios.post` is asynchronous.  You've passed it a callback in `.then()`, but you aren't awaiting anything.  So you're checking for the value in storage before you've set that value.

Instead of using the callback on `.then()`, stick with your current standard of using `await`.  Something like this:

```
try {
  let response = await axios.post('/login', {
    email : email,
    password: password
  });
  let info = response.data.data.token;
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('scute-user-token', info);
  // you don't need to read back the token, you already have it in "info"
  if (info !== null){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} catch (e) {
  Alert.alert(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`axis.post` is asynchronous, so when post API is being called it'll run in the background and next statements will continue to get executed.

So in your implementation `await AsyncStorage.getItem('scute-user-token')` is being called before you get the response from the server. Initially it'll be `null` that's the reason why always `false` is being returned.

In order to make this work you can use two methods

- Using `async-await`

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const response = axios.post('/login', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });
    let info = response.data.data.token;
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('scute-user-token', info);
    return info !== null
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert(error);
    return false;
  }
};
```

- By returning from `.then` itself

```
const login = async (email, password) => {
  return axios
    .post('/login', {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    })
    .then(async response => {
      let info = response.data.data.token;
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('scute-user-token', info);
      return info !== null;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      Alert.alert(error);
      return false;
    });
};
```

Hope this helps.